# Issue with JAXB inheritance and @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb

The issue is to map two similiar `XML`s to single class structure:

xml1: `<a1><b1 b1Value="xxxx1"/></a1>`

xml2: `<a2><b2 b2Value="xxxx2"/></a2>`

Due to legacy code I can not create special abstract common classes, so I have to use simple inheritance:

1) class `A1` and its subclass `A2`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "a1")
@XmlSeeAlso(A2.class)
public class A1 {    
    protected B1 b;    
    @XmlElement(name = "b1")
    public B1 getB() {  return b;  }    
    public void setB(B1 b) { this.b = b; }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "a2")
public class A2 extends A1 {        
     @XmlElement(name = "b2")
     @Override
     public B1 getB() { return super.getB(); }

     @Override
     public void setB(B1 b) { super.setB(b);  }
}
```

2) Class `B1` and its subclass `B2`:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(B2.class)
public class B1 {        
     protected String value;        
     @XmlAttribute(name = "b1Value")
     public String getValue() {  return value; }        
     public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}

public class B2 extends B1 {    
    @XmlAttribute(name = "b2Value")
    @Override
    public String getValue() { return super.getValue(); }    
    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) { super.setValue(value); }
}
```

The problem appears when trying to parse `xml2`:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A1.class);
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
A1 entity = (A1) um.unmarshal(new StringReader("<a2><b2 b2Value="xxxx2"/></a2>"));
```

In this case `entity` object becomes instance of class `A2` - it is correct. But internal field `b` contains instance of class `B1` and its internal `value` is `null` (see picture below):

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with setters arguments types in subclasses and getters returning types.

To solve it, it is necessary to change `B1` to `B2` inside `A2` getters and setters.

So in `A2` class it should be not `void setB(B1 b) { super.setB(b);  }`, but `void setB(B2 b) { super.setB(b);  }`, and instead of `B1 getB() { return super.getB(); }` it should be `B2 getB() { return (B2)super.getB(); }`.